# Unexpected output for posts and gets. Scraping from a website that uses javascript

Tags: javascript, python, post, get, python-requests

I am using python 2.7 on Windows 7 to scrape data from a website. When you login to the website through /index.cfm it takes you to an announcement page with some general policy updates. The url does not change so I'm assuming theres some javascript involved. When you click the ok button to accept the terms it takes you to your user profile page. Still no URL redirect, still /index.cfm.

The object of the program is to get data from particular item pages

My code is as follows:

```
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

payload = { xxx }
s= requests.session()
s.mount = (MainURL,MyAdapter())

result = s.post(loginURL, data=payload)
item = s.get(ItemURL)
print ItemURL
print item.text
```

Note that loginURL and MainURL happen to be the same.

The problem im having is that s.get(ItemURL) is returning the source code from the policy announcement page mentioned above.

If I copy the output of "print ItemURL" to my browser it will take me to the site Im looking for. However the "print item.text" prints source code for the announcement page.

I think this page is shown on every fresh login regardless of URL. Is this a cookies issue? How do I address this in the get call? Ive tried the following also with no avail:

```
item = s.get(ItemURL, allow_redirects = False)
```

EDIT: For clarification: You login in browser to www.example.com/index.cfm and it takes you to a general announcements page also www.example.com/index.cfm. Then you click ok and it takes you to your user profile, also www.example.com/index.cfm.

Im logging in using

```
result = s.post('https://www.example.com/index.cfm', data=payload)
```

print result.text will output the source code for the announcements page.

Then I try to get:

```
item = s.get('https://www.example.com/index.cfm?item=142')
```

print item.text also outputs the source code for the announcements page when I'd like it to print the source for the page of item 142. The link takes me where I want when copied into the browser